# Loop for generating 6 non-equal numbers is failling (java)

Tags: java, loops, random, boolean

I have here the following code:

```
    import java.util.Random;

    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int numnovo, numeros[], j;
            boolean igual;
            numeros = new int[6];

            Random rand = new Random();

            numnovo = rand.nextInt(60)+1;
            numeros[0] = numnovo;

            System.out.println("Número 1: " + numeros[0]);

            for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
            {
                do
                {
                    igual = true;
                    numnovo = rand.nextInt(60)+1;
                    j=0;
                    while(j<=i && igual)
                    {
                        igual = (numnovo == numeros[j++]);
                    }
                }while(igual);
                numeros[i] = numnovo;
                System.out.println("Número " + (i+1) + ": " + numeros[i]);
            }
    }
}
```

So, here's one of the results I got from it:

```
numeros[0]=48 
numeros[1]=31
numeros[2]=52
numeros[3]=25 - repeated
numeros[4]=18
numeros[5]=25 - repeated
```

Yet, while analyzing the code, I'd suppose it would come to the following situation inside of the loop:

```
i=5

j=0 numeros[0]=48   false
j=1 numeros[1]=31   false
j=2 numeros[2]=52   false
**j=3   numeros[3]=25   true**
```

Specifically in the marked line, I'd suppose the condition for the while loop (j<=i && igual) to be satisfied and, therefore, it would exit the loop and generate a new number, but that didn't happen, it went straight through and considered it a valid value.

I've cracking my head open around this problem for a day or so already and can't seen to find a solution, and it is something that happens in about 10% of all execution, so it wasn't an isolated case.

I tried to look into the "j vs i" relation as in "Is the repeated number always close to the previous one" but in some executions the repeated number would be the numeros[0] and numeros[5], and in others it could be like the numeros[0] and numeros[1], so the thesis didn't work.

I also tried to change condition from && to ||, but got didn't change it even a bit.

I tried also a few different condition sintaxes, as going in the opposite direction (using false statements instead of true), and also different loops instead of Do-While, and still no luck.

So... any help here?

Comment: Just a little advice, changing the variable names to English will help a lot of people help you better

Comment: I am guessing you can use a `Set`?

Answer (score 2):

```
while(j<=i && igual)
{
    igual = (numnovo == numeros[j++]);
}
```

You stop the first time a number isn't equal, so in your example case, you only check if the first number is equal.

In this case, you usually want to try the opposite:

```
do {
    boolean found = false;
    numnovo = rand.nextInt(60)+1;
    j=0;
    while (j<=i){
        if (numnovo == numeros[j++]){
            found = true;
        }
    }
}while(found);
```

---

From the comments

> The idea was not to use any if in the code, which is why I was using the syntax igual = (numnovo == numeros[j++])

In that case, you can try:

```
do {
    boolean found = false;
    numnovo = rand.nextInt(60)+1;
    j=0;
    while (j<=i){
        found = numnovo == numeros[j++] || found;
    }
}while(found);
```

Or, like @nullptr's answer, break from the loop: `while (j<=i && !found)`

Comment: Thanks for the help! It worked! I just didn't understand better the idea that my loop was only checking for the first number to be equal or not. Would you care to explain, please?

Comment: @LuizHenriqueCarneiroGonalve If the first number was not equal, iqual = false, so your loop breaks. So 25 != 48? True, so you end your loop (`&& iqual == false`)

Comment: But really, you want to check all of the other numbers, so you want the loop to continue

Comment: @LuizHenriqueCarneiroGonalve Added in a response to your other comments

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the do-while loop to

```java
do
{
    igual = false;
    numnovo = rand.nextInt(60)+1;
    j=0;
    while(j<=i && !igual)
    {
        igual = (numnovo == numeros[j++]);
    }
}while(igual);
```

Your code only exits the loop when the first non-equal number is encountered. Instead, assume that the numbers are non-equal, and exit the loop when a repeated number is encountered.

Comment: Both solutions gave here, by you and Mars worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is more complicated than it needs to be. You've got an extra loop that appears to terminate too early. Here's a simpler approach:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length;) {
        int randomNum = r.nextInt(6);
        boolean equal = false;
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            int arrNum = nums[j];
            if(arrNum == randomNum) {
                equal = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!equal) {
            nums[i++] = randomNum;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The idea was not to use any if in the code, which is why I was using the syntax igual = (numnovo == numeros[j++]);

Yet, thanks for the help! It works as well :)

Comment: Ah ok, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

```
igual = false; // default no repeat;
numnovo = rand.nextInt(60)+1;
j=0;
while(j<=i && !(igual = (numnovo == numeros[j++]))); // if repeat break inline loop and generate a new number
```